# System throws time out error during on click on login button

Tags: java, android-volley

In my android java app, from the LoginActivity I am calling the "LoginRegisterWebService" restful webservice, but on click on the login button 
system throws a "Some error occured > com.android.volley.TimeOutError". Here I am using the Remix OS player emulator. Already gone through few answers related to volley timeout errors and increased the timeout duration,
but it doesn't make any difference. Set the breakpoint in this step 'public void onResponse(String s)', but the system is not going inside onResponse. I have switched off the firewall too.
Could someone please help me to figure out the problem
[image]
Please find my Gradle settings

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.foodies.myfoodies"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

// LogingActivity code give below

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailBox, passwordBox;
    Button loginButton;
    TextView registerLink;
    String URL = "http://[ip address]:8081/MyFoodies/LoginRegisterWebService/login";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        emailBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailBox);
        passwordBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
        loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        registerLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.registerLink);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String rs) {
                        if(rs.equals("true")){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Home.class));
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> "+volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("email", emailBox.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("password", passwordBox.getText().toString());
                        return parameters;
                    }
                };

                request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        7000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                int socketTimeout = 10000;//10 seconds - change to what you want
                RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                request.setRetryPolicy(policy);
                rQueue.add(request);

            }
        });

        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

//Following is the Webservice.java code

```
@Path("/LoginRegisterWebService")
public class LoginRegisterWebService {

    final static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/foodhub";
    final static String user = "root";
    final static String pass = "root";

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password){
        String result="false";

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from foodhub.login where email=? and UserPassword=?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()){
                result = "true";
            }

            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String register(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password){
        String result="false";
        int x = 0;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into login(email, UserPassword) values(?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            x = ps.executeUpdate();

            if(x==1){
                result = "true";
            }

            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons that may cause this.

1. Is the API server running on the port you have specified?
2. Does your IP have access to the IP address?
3. The API execution script is taking too long to execute / send response back? The webserver have a max timeout limit.

Comment: I will check and confirm the port address soon

Comment: I have given the correct port address but no luck yet

Comment: I have given the correct port address but no luck yet and still receiving volley.timeouterror

Comment: Can you print some value before the mysql connection? See if your script runs until that line #

Comment: Also, I would recommend using an ORM like hibernate http://hibernate.org/orm/. It really helps in handling mysql connections. You wouldn't have define connections for each method. Hibernate will intelligently handle mysql connections.

Comment: I have added a line in the try{}catch{} of the "LoginRegisterWebService" to print Log.d("myTag", "This is my message"); System is not going into that line itself.

Comment: hmmm. you will have to reverse debug it line by line.

Comment: I have added necessary breakpoints, but unable to find the real problem. Can any one please help